# OutOfMemoryException while heap is half full

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

I get `OutOfMemoryException` while it seems like the heap still has plenty of space left.

My own logs report - VM Memory used 22.28G out of 48G

logs from `-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1PrintHeapRegions` seem to agree that only 25G out 48G is being used

```
[Eden: 0.0B(2448.0M)->0.0B(2448.0M) Survivors: 0.0B->0.0B Heap: 24.9G(48.0G)->24.9G(48.0G)]

 159.360: [G1Ergonomics (Heap Sizing) attempt heap expansion, reason: allocation request failed, allocation request: 48 bytes]
 159.360: [G1Ergonomics (Heap Sizing) expand the heap, requested expansion amount: 16777216 bytes, attempted expansion amount: 16777216 bytes]
 159.360: [G1Ergonomics (Heap Sizing) did not expand the heap, reason: heap already fully expanded]
```

The problem seems to be specific to G1.  While using the default gc algorithm on Java 8, the memory utilization gets much closer to the `-mx48G` threshold before the `OutOfMemoryException` is thrown.

I am using the following parameters
`-XX:+UseG1GC -mx48G`

Answer (score 0):

Tried the same use case in Java 11.  It ran out of memory at about the same time, but reported memory utilization at 98%.  That makes sense.

Seems like Java 8 incorrectly reports memory utilization.